# How to separate Topics when having multiple Apps in one project

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've only used one App in a single project in Firebase until now.
My next step is to use three Apps (App dev, App prod, App stage etc) in a single project and I can't find out how to separate the Topics sent to a specific App.

Current setup is:

1. App registers on a topic
2. Server notifies changes to the specific App, on listening on that topic (Not all three Apps)

Currently I don't see how it could possibly know which App it should send to.
Firebase supports multiple server-keys but not specifing which one should go to which app within same project.

I was looking for a solution where the server might specify which AppId it should send to depending on which App, but I can't find anything about that either...

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Regards

Comment: You can define which play-services.json would be for any type of build type and flavors. Look for it in Google

Comment: Yes, I have three different configurations in my google-service.json but I still don't on which way the topics will be directed to which app when they all utilize the same server-key.